# DNS Hostinger to WFS?

Tags: qgis, wfs, hosting

I have a domain in Hostinger, recently I have created a DNS that point to the IP where is GeoServer, the body is the next:

```
http://www.(name):8080/geoserver/nameoflayer/wfs
```

But he doesn't run in QGIS it. Already have configured the port in the firewall. Is there someone who has experience with this?

Comment: does the link work, (give any response) in a web browser?  Is web traffic on port 8080 enabled?

Comment: Don´t run in a web browser and yes, web traffic on port 8080 enabled

Comment: If it doesn't run in a web browser, the issue is not with QGIS, the issue is with your server/service.